# Node Discord.js Axios API Indexing

Tags: node.js, api, indexing, discord.js

I want to index through a list of items stored in a json file and call to each API and bring back data. The below code shows indexing/map working by building an API link, but how do I get the whole API call and message to be inside the indexing so each list item is called and returned by the API:

```
// {"342671641006047252":["MSFT","AMZN","CVNA","TEAM"]}
console.log(list);

// This is indexing through the list and bulding the link
const tickers = list
  .map((ticker, index) => `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/${ticker}?apikey=6c7ee1f3c7a666228979fa0678fa22a3`)
  return message.channel.send(tickers)
  
// This is going to the api for list[0]
axios.get('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/'+list[0]+'?apikey=6c7ee1f3c7a666228979fa0678fa22a3').then(resp => {
console.log(resp.data);
let symbol = resp.data[0].symbol;
let price = resp.data[0].price;
let changesPercentage = resp.data[0].changesPercentage;
return message.channel.send({embed: {
    color: 8311585,
    fields: [{
        name: "Ticker",
        value: `${symbol}`,
        inline: "true"
      },
      {
        name: "Price",
        value: `${price}`,
        inline: "true"
      },
      {
        name: "Change %",
        value: `${changesPercentage}`,
        inline: "true"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind on this one! I used forEach instead of .map and got it working!